# matplotlib get numpy array index location on click

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a numpy array which I plot with

```
plt.imshow(img_right, cmap = plt.cm.gray,picker=True)
```

I then attache an on-pick handler to it

```
win.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event',onclick)
```

I then click on the image location. My reuirment is to get the array index of the numpy 2-D array which was used to plot the data originally

I tried the following the the onpick even handler

```
print dir(event_pick)
event=event_pick.mouseevent
print dir(temp)
```

I see that none of these contain a ind attribute.

How do I get the array index from the clicked location?(I dont need the xydata, I need the closest array index)

Comment: You need to take the xdata and ydata and calculate back to the index, which is easily possible for imshow plots.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, How do I do something like that? For a given xdata and ydata will there not be many location which have a similar value? Could you please post some more information as to how this is possible?

Comment: Look e.g. at the `pick` method of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48423236/reflect-event-handling-on-multiple-subplots/48427458#48427458).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, Thanks a lot. If you post that as an answer I can accept it